# Create a circular carousel in React Js without any library

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am hoping to recreate the carousel present on this [site](https://aniwave.to/home). I want to achieve the same functionality without using any library.
I have come across a lot of resources on how to achieve that. Most of them were creating two copies of the carousel track and then switching in between but I do not want to do that. The below code works fine as long as I am sliding within the boundary elements (1st and last slide). How can I switch from the last slide to the first slide and vice versa? I can switch to the first slide from the last slide by adjusting the left offset but that would not make it look like an infinite slider. I want to make it look like the one on the site. Is appending first slide after the last the only way to achieve?

```
import {useRef, useEffect} from "react";
import {details} from "./constants";

const App = () => {
  const carousel_track = useRef();
  const container = useRef();
  let counter = 0;
  const card = useRef();
  const prevSlide = () => {
    const width = card.current.offsetWidth;
    counter--;
    carousel_track.current.style.left = -width * counter + "px";
  };
  const nextSlide = () => {
    const width = card.current.offsetWidth;
    counter++;
    carousel_track.current.style.left = -width * counter + "px";
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code === "ArrowRight") nextSlide();
      if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") prevSlide();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-screen  h-screen flex items-center bg-slate-500">
      <div
        ref={container}
        className="w-screen h-2/3 transition-all  overflow-x-hidden relative border-cyan-800 border-4"
      >
        <div
          onClick={prevSlide}
          className="absolute cursor-pointer  text-2xl text-white z-10 left-0 top-1/2"
        >
          Prev
        </div>
        <div
          onClick={nextSlide}
          className="absolute cursor-pointer text-2xl text-white z-10 right-0 top-1/2"
        >
          Next
        </div>
        <div
          ref={carousel_track}
          className="w-[200%] h-full flex transition-all justify-start items-center absolute bg-red-800"
        >
          {details.map((slide) => (
            <div
              ref={card}
              className="w-screen h-full flex-shrink-0"
              key={slide.title}
            >
              <div className="rounded-lg h-full">
                <img
                  src={slide.image}
                  alt="image"
                  className="rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Sure, it's entirely possible to do that, but we're not going to write the code ("share the solution") for you. You'll need to try, and come back if you have a problem doing so.

Comment: "without any library" well, ReactJS could potentially be viewed as a library in some contexts so this seems contradictory.

Comment: I meant the library for sliders/animation.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with a basic example of a circular carousel in React without using any external libraries.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Carousel = ({ images }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const nextImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % images.length);
  };

  const prevImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '300px', margin: 'auto' }}>
      <button onClick={prevImage} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '10px' }}>
        {'<'}
      </button>
      <img
        src={images[currentIndex]}
        alt={`Image ${currentIndex + 1}`}
        style={{ width: '100%', borderRadius: '8px' }}
      />
      <button onClick={nextImage} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '50%', right: '10px' }}>
        {'>'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const images = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/300',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/300',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/300',
    // Add more image URLs as needed
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Circular Carousel</h1>
      <Carousel images={images} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```